# How to Wrap the Points of a 3D Clustering Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization, cluster-analysis, plot-themes

I am doing clustering and have a plot as below:-

```
GaussianRandomData[n_Integer,p_,sigma_]:=Table[p+{Re[#],Im[#],RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,sigma]]}&[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,sigma]] E^(I RandomReal[{0,2 π}])],{n}];
datapairs=BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234];Join[GaussianRandomData[100,{15,10,0},.3],GaussianRandomData[100,{12,13,0},.2],GaussianRandomData[100,{10,11,0},.4],GaussianRandomData[100,{12,13,0},0.1]]];
data1=FindClusters[datapairs];
ListPointPlot3D[data1]
```

[image: The plot of virus outbreak]

Is it possible to wrap the points up by some surfaces (either transparent or not; either just coloring at the boundaries or filled up; either elliptic or irregular)? That would be similar to the following 2D case:-

[image]

If being wrapped by surfaces is not possible, is it possible to just add lines linking the points of the same cluster?

Many thanks!

Comment: Look at `ConvexHullMesh`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 Show[ListPointPlot3D[data1, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[3]}], 
 Table[{HighlightMesh[ConvexHullMesh[data1[[i]]], 
    Style[2, ColorData[97, i], Opacity[0.2]]]}, {i, 3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there a way to change the surfaces into 3 different colors? I think the change should be at `Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]`?

Comment: `Style[2, Orange, Opacity[0.5]]`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for or what you want is smallest ball or ellipsoid that contain all points?

Comment: I just want a clear illustration to show separated clusters. In my real data, there are several thousand points and there are around 20 to 100 clusters overlapping each other. It is likely that I will keep refreshing the plot with different parameters to analyze the data, so I hope the selected method would be more computationally efficient (or not too worse) than the other methods.

Comment: For my real case in which the clusters overlapping each other, I noted that `ConvexHullMesh` is a better solution than `BoundingRegion[#,"FastEllipsoid"]&`, since the ellipsoid would be much larger than the hull, making the graph less illustrative since the large ellipsoids overlap each other too much.

Answer (score 9):

Yu could use `BoundingRegion` with the `"FastEllipsoid"` as second argument:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Transpose[{
    ColorData[97] /@ Range[3],
    Point /@ data1
    }],
  Opacity[0.25],
  Transpose[{
    ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], 
    BoundingRegion[#, "FastEllipsoid"] & /@ data1
    }]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

See also the documenttion of `BoundingRegion` for further bounding shapes.